# LDAP + два PHP-файла: один возвращает результат, второй - нет. Почему?

Tags: php, ldap

Сделал копию рабочего файла в ту же директорию. Запускаю. ldap_coonect(), ldap_bind() работает, но ldap_search() ничего не возвращает.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть проблема в неправильном синтаксисе.
Что пишет сам LDAP? У него есть [ldap_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ldap-error.php)

Comment: Была проблема с передаваемыми параметрами. Спасибо за наводку.